# AWS ToolKit docker container not resolving internal service URIs

Tags: docker, aws-sam-cli, docker-network, aws-toolkit

I am running an AWS Lambda locally via AWS Toolkit.  The function, through a long dependency chain, calls an internal service endpoint that throws a `ConnectionTimeoutException`.  That endpoint works when called locally.

Toolkit spins up a container to run the lambda in using the `bridge` docker network running on my local machine.  My local machine is also running a `proxy` client in another container, and using `docker network inspect bridge` from my local terminal, I can see both the `proxy` and Toolkit containers are registered on the bridge network.  When I shell into the running lambda container, my `cUrl` command to the internal service times out.  That same command on my local machine succeeds.

Shouldn't the `cUrl` command work from within the lambda container?

> local machine bridge network

[image]

> connection time out exception

`failed: connect timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to internal.service.uri:80`

Answer (score 0):

Our SQUID proxy does not support service discovery.
This means the container has to have environment vars set to the proxy IP:

```
export http_proxy=http://172.17.0.2:3128
export HTTP_PROXY=http://172.17.0.2:3128
export https_proxy=http://172.17.0.2:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://172.17.0.2:3128
export NO_PROXY=localhost
```

then it works.

next step is to figure out how to set those within the, container via Aws Toolkit